# IMP-00058: ORACLE error 1017 encountered

Tags: importerror

I am using Oracle 11g client 32bit on all my servers and i have proceeded with all the dump imports the very same way I am doing here.

Firstly I create the user with default tablespace
Secondly I alter the user quota unlimited on tablespace
Thirdly I grant connect resource dba to the user.

Then I exit from Oracle and this is my import command

**C:\Users\romit.poladiya>imp fajbdummy/fa@dmate file='E:\dump\fajblatest.dmp' full=Y;**

I have always been doing this and I do not know why I have not been able to import this time. Please assist. Let me know if you require any more information

Thanking the team in advance,
Romit

Answer (score 0):

ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

**Cause:** An invalid username or password was entered in an attempt to log on to Oracle. The username and password must be the same as was specified in a GRANT CONNECT statement. If the username and password are entered together, the format is: username/password.

**Cure:** Use the correct username & password. Check the system to make sure that the username exists, and set the password if necessary.

Comment: I have already verified all the mentioned above. I can connect the newly created user through **sqlplus**. I have verified the user name from **select username from dba_users** and also altered to a new password and re-connected with **sqlplus**. But cannot import dump

Answer (score 0):

The following issue can be closed as I was able to do the tnsping but unfortunately my oracle went into an **Idle Instance** while I was connecting. Earlier it was not an issue and I have no idea whatever happened and the the oracle just went into **Shutdown**